# Alguém sabe qual codigo pra importa imagem word pelo macro?

Tags: macro, microsoft-word

Quero que o macro puxe de um arquivo Word a imagem e dimensiona a imagem em outro arquivo assim que eu apertar f5, quando digo dimensiona me refiro a ocupar uma folha inteira.

Comment: Não repita perguntas, siga as orientações feitas na pergunta original e então edite-a para que se adeque ao objetivo do Stack Overflow em Português. Os **comentários** aqui foram bloqueados aqui para que possa prosseguir na pergunta [original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/589188/137387).